# Mysql - joining labels and values table and including not referenced labels as null

Tags: mysql, join, select, reference, null

The following problem has been bugging me for some time now. I have two tables in my database.

First I have a table holding labels, referenced values.

```
| option_id | option_name |
|-----------|-------------|
| 1         | Blue        |
| 2         | Red         |
| 3         | Black       |
```

Then I have the second table with the actual values

```
| record_id | option_id | first_name | profession |
|-----------|-----------|------------|------------|
| 1         | 2         | James      | Clerk      |
| 2         | 2         | Ethan      | Clerk      |
| 3         | 1         | Marian     | Nurse      |
| 4         | 3         | Bob        | Nurse      |
| 5         | 3         | Paul       | Nurse      |
```

How can I join these two tables in MySQL so I get all the options listed for each of the professions even when there is no reference value so it will show up as NULL?

So the table would look something like:

```
| profession | option_name | first_name |
|------------|-------------|------------|
| Clerk      | Blue        | NULL       |
| Clerk      | Red         | James      |
| Clerk      | Red         | Ethan      |
| Clerk      | Black       | NULL       |
| Nurse      | Blue        | Marian     |
| Nurse      | Red         | NULL       |
| Nurse      | Black       | Bob        |
| Nurse      | Black       | Paul       |
```

Any help would be appreciated. Here is the sample database

```
CREATE TABLE options (
  option_id INT,
  option_name TEXT
);

INSERT INTO options VALUES (1, 'Blue');
INSERT INTO options VALUES (2, 'Red');
INSERT INTO options VALUES (3, 'Black');

CREATE TABLE records (
  record_id INT,
  option_id INT,
  first_name TEXT,
  profession TEXT
);

INSERT INTO records VALUES (1, 2, 'James','Clerk');
INSERT INTO records VALUES (2, 2, 'Ethen','Clerk');
INSERT INTO records VALUES (3, 1, 'Marian','Nurse');
INSERT INTO records VALUES (4, 3, 'Bob', 'Nurse');
INSERT INTO records VALUES (5, 3, 'Paul', 'Nurse');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enumerate the professions from the `records` table, `cross join` table `options` to generate all possible combinations, then bring the `records` table with a `left join`:

```
select p.profession, o.option_name, r.first_name
from (select distinct profession from records) p
cross join options o
left join records r 
    on  r.option_id = o.option_id 
    and r.profession = p.profession
order by p.profession, o.option_name
```

Comment: Is there any difference/cost/benefit in omitting the subquery, and adding DISTINCT to the main query

Comment: Thanks so much, actually I learned a lot from this answer!